# Responsive width on ContentImagebyKey

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, content-builder

I'm using `ContentImagebyKey()` to pull in a dynamic image for an event specific email that changes based on location.  That being said I have a CSV that's serving me the customerkey field.

The images are pulling in fine, but we're using a responsive layout, and I'd like the image to scale to 100% width in mobile.

```
<td class="responsive-td" width="216" style="width:36%;">
  <a href="%%=redirectto(@link)=%%" border="0">
    %%=ContentImagebyKey(@image,"Default")=%%
  </a>
</td>
```

what this results in is the image at it's native resolution off to the left. I can center the whole section, but I haven't found a way to specify `style="width: 100%"` for my mobile clients since I don't have access to the `<img>` tag itself.

Does anyone have a good solution to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I inspected, the ampscript function outputs the very basic image html attributes.

```
<img title="xxxx" alt="xxxxx" src="public url of content" border="0">
```

I found the best way to add attributes to the `<image>` tag would be to use [replace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Replace.htm) function.

Here is the sample code:

```
%%=Replace(ContentImagebyKey("Customer_Key"),'>','style="width:100%;">')=%%
```

**Result:**

```
<img title="xxxx" alt="xxxxx" src="public url of content" border="0" style="width:100%;">
```

> Note: You can add more attributes by using [concat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Concat.htm) function.

Comment: Brilliant.  Well done, works perfectly! I had to add the closing `>` in the replace field, in case you want to edit to add it.  Thank you!

Comment: @KevinIllick no worries. glad I could help :)