# Is it possible automatically to save content builder published urls into a DE?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automation, url, content-builder

I have 3 images (imagine: logo, img1, img2) uploaded and published in Content Builder.

I want to add thos published URLs to a DE, so in logo's line I add url from logo image.

If there a just 3, its easy to do it manually but thinking of more images, I would like to know I there is a way to automate it and have all urls stored automatically in a DE with the name of the image.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, Constanza. Can you explain in more details what you are trying to achieve? A single sentence in your question does not provide a lot of context, and hence makes it extremely difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend using Ampscript's [contentimagebykey function](https://ampscript.guide/contentimagebykey/). You should apply unique and logical keys to your images, e.g. "logo_brandX", "logo_brandY". This will let you use an ampscript parameter to fetch the right logo.

You can use it in following way, assuming you are setting the image based on a value in sendable data extension (let's call it *brand*):

```ampscript
%%[
SET @brand = AttributeValue("brand")
SET @imagekey = Concat("logo_",@brand)
]%%

Here goes the image:<br/>
%%=ContentImageByKey(@imagekey,"defaultLogo")=%%
```

As an example, I have created an image here, which is uploaded and once uploaded, I have updated the key to *logo_audi*:

[image]

Then, according to the amscript code above, I would have a value of *audi* in my record in sendable data extension, then this value would be combined with *logo_* in the Concat function, allowing *logo_audi* to be displayed by ContentImageByKey.

A good practice would also be to add a default logo, if there is a recipient with a brand which doesn't match any uploaded images. It will then be displayed instead.

See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/209997/responsive-width-on-contentimagebykey/210019#210019) on how to manage additional parameters in the img tag when using this function.